# Is putting a warning enough to make your hacking software legal?

Tags: copyright, software, licensing

I never wrote a license or a readme for a program.
This is my readme.txt inside the folder of the program that gets downloaded :

> ATTENTION: HACKING IS ILLEGAL USE THIS AT YOUR OWN GMAIL ACCOUNTS  THE PROGRAM DEVELOPER IS NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE CAUSED BY THE PROGRAM
>
> contact program Developer at example@gmail.com .
>
> ENJOY !

My program does illegal stuff but it can be used on yourself without inflicting any damage to others, I saw many other programs that can be used for illegal purposes but are published normally, for example: nmap, hydra and Jhon the ripper.

Is this enough to make it legal to publish? If not what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

In many jurisdictions, it is possible to legally publish software which may aid in hacking. Consider the well-known [OWASP WebGoat](https://owasp.org/www-project-webgoat/), a training program for computer security. If you consider yourself an ethical professional, take a look at the number of warnings they have peppered over their software, e.g. on the bottom of the linked page.

What is necessary in *your* jurisdiction depends on where you live, and you haven't disclosed that. In the worst case, "exporting" it might violate [arms control legislation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States#Current_status).